# Solving for $x$ and $y$ image coordinate given a 3D point

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, geometric-optics, geometry, camera

I have a 3D point, $(X, Y ,Z)$ and I want to know where it's imaged, $(u, v)$. I'm assuming a pinhole camera model with no lens distortion. I have the distance from the pinhole to the object ($z$), as well as the focal length ($f$). Using similar triangles, I know that $v = Y\frac{f}{z}$. This makes sense because $Y$ is the "height" of the point in 3D, and $v$ is the "height" of the point in 2D.

What I'm failing to recover is $u$, the horizontal coordinate of the imaged point, $u$.

Comment: How does a pinhole camera have a focal length?

Comment: If $f$ is just the distance from the aperture to the screen/film, why do you think the calculation of $u$ from $X$ is different from the calculation of $v$ from $Y$?

Comment: Isn’t the focal length the distance between the pinhole and the image plane? Anyway, let’s say I image the point (5, 4, 1). Clearly X and Y are not equal to each other. So I’m guessing that u is not equal to v? That’s probably because the scaling factor of f/z changes right?

Comment: It's just ray optics. $u=X\frac{f}{z}$ the same as $v=Y\frac{f}{z}$. But with a lensed camera, the focal length is a characteristic of the lens, and that distance is the only place you can put the image (for an object at infinity). With a pinhole, you can move your screen/film how you like in the $w$ direction and still get an image.

Comment: By same you don’t mean equal right?

Comment: Same math. Different values.

Comment: I have implemented this in Mathematica; see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/172894/26956). The only thing this does on top of HiddenBabel's answer, is to apply a rotational and translational transformation to allow for arbitrary viewpoints and camera orientations.

Answer (score 0):

You're projecting the vector $(-X,-Y,-Z)$ onto the $uv$ plane. But the normal of the plane is simply $(0,0,1)$, so you get a projected vector of $(-X,-Y,0)/z$. Then you scale it by $f$ to put it on the image plane, $\frac{f}{z}(-X,-Y,0)$.

Comment: Why negative values?

Comment: The vector pointing from the opening to the object is in the opposite direction from the vector pointing from the opening to the image. This is why pictures taken in a camera obscura are inverted.